# Centered section title in fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

`fancyhdr` automatically puts the section title on the right header. When I try

```
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\chead{\rightmark}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\end{document}
```

nothing appears in the header. Help!

Comment: What class are you using? If it's `article`, you should say also `\lhead{}` to clear the left field and use `\chead{\leftmark}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please always post *complete* documents that show the problem.[image]

LaTeX only distinguishes left and right marks when it is using a `twoside` setting:

Furthermore `\rightmark` is by default the set by subsection at the top of the current page.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{}
\chead{\rightmark}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\section{aaaa}
\subsection{bbb}
ccc

\clearpage
bbb
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's the `\leftmark` and it's not centered.

Comment: @egreg sorry You just got your comment in before I deleted the answer, undeleted it with a revised image:-)

Comment: I realized that \rightmark returns subsection title and \leftmark returns section title. I somehow thought that \leftmark returns chapter title and therefore irrelevant. Thanks for your help!